# How to show users profile picture

Tags: php, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I want to show my users profile picture when the sign in . When they click the `change profile picture` button, their picture gets saved into the directory and then the database . I don't know where to start. How do I show whatever picture the user has, as their profile picture ?

profile.php:

```
<form id="form2" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p id="p1">Change profile picture:</p> <br />
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br />
<br><input id="sub1" type="submit" value="Change profile picture" name="change"><br />
</form>

<!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<img id="myImg" src="default.jpg" width="200" height="150">
```

EDIT!!!!

```
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
$errors= array();
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

$extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
 $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPG, JPEG or PNG file.";
}

if($file_size > 2097152) {
 $errors[]='File size must be 2 MB';
}

 if(empty($errors)==true) {
 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/uploads/".$file_name);

$store=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users SET userPic='$userPic' WHERE username='$username'");
mysqli_query($conn,$store);
 echo "Success";
}else{
 print_r($errors);
 echo"it failed";
}
}
?>

<?php
$getimg = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT userPic FROM users WHERE username='" . 
$username . "'");
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($getimg);
$img = $rows['userPic'];

?>



<img id="myImg" src="images/uploads/<?php echo $img?>"  alt="<?php echo $img ?>" width="200" height="150">
```

Comment: select the user info you need from the db (id, username, profile picture, etc), optionally store it in session, then use that data to display it on page..?

Comment: This is how I show the username `<center><h5><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h5></center>`

Comment: Is it something similar to that ?

Comment: Assuming you do things normally and store the image name in the database and the image in the file system somewhere publically available then yes. something like `<img src="/images/profile_pictures/<?= $_SESSION['profile_picture'] ?>"/>` should work. Note that you of course have to make sure the path for the image is correct to match however you have it

Comment: @JimL I just updated my question . Please take a look

Comment: where do you store userPic in the session?

Comment: No where . I think

Comment: That makes it a problem using it ;) You also try to use it without echoing it, you either need to add an echo to that line or use the shorthand echo syntax as I had in my comment (which I prefer). If you add the userPic to the session in your login code this should work fine after a logout/login

Comment: Now I am getting this warning `Notice: Undefined index: userPic`

Comment: I put this `$_SESSION['userPic'] = $_POST['userPic'];
`

Comment: And I added echo to the line like this `<img src="/images/uploads/<?php echo $_SESSION['userPic'] ?>" "width="200" height="150" />
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so my first question is do you use a database of some sort. If you do create a field inside the users table called "avatar" this is where we will store the filename. Secondly in your localhost directory create a file called "uploads" inside here we will store the file names for the pictures. 
Secondly do you have sessions? If so i have defined the session as $user so change that to fit your sessions. Then simply add this code. I have it all in the same file but you can make it a separate file if you'd like.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $database = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$user = $_SESSION['username'];

   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152) {
         $errors[]='File size must be 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true) {
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);

        $store=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE tbl SET avatar='$file_name' WHERE username='$user'");
        mysqli_query($conn,$store);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
         echo"it failed";
      }
   }
?>

      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p id="p1">Change profile picture:</p> <br />
         <input type="file" name="image" />
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>

<?php

$getimg = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT avatar FROM tbl WHERE username='$user'");
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($getimg);
$img = $rows['avatar'];

?>



<img id="myImg" src="uploads/<?php echo $img?>"  alt="<?php echo $img ?>" width="200" height="150">
```

Please ask any questions i will be happy to help you through this.

Comment: Okay I will update my code and show you what I've done and what I see

Comment: alright add comment when it is done - note make sure you edit the sql queries to fit your tbl connection

Comment: Ok and what happens when you try to upload an image?

Comment: Please check "username" is the same field as in your database. Do you use sessions on this page? And have you created a field in your database next to where you store usernames?

Comment: i just moved the code that uploads the image and put it in my upload.php file . When I click the change profile picture button and I go to upload.php it's just a blank screen

Comment: Ok so make sure in your form "action="upload.php" i would just have it on the same page it makes it easier and can stop people spamming images

Comment: Test it in the same file so take out the "upload.php"

Comment: Now nothing changes . The database has the old picture and the directory isn't updated

Comment: So question 1. is your database field VARCHAR(255 characters) 2nd. is that field called avatar. 3. Is your user field called username in your database? - if not do all these things

Comment: yes my database is VARCHAR 255 . No the field is called `userPic` and yes my username field is called username in the db

Comment: If you can do all those things and copy my code back over then you wont have to change anything - only have to change the table name

Comment: Any errors? Also have you started a session at the very top of this page?

Comment: Now. Could you please send me the exact route to the folder where your php file is currently. e.g. C:\xampp\htdocs

Comment: `C:\wamp\www\Interpage\images\uploads`

Comment: Ok and can you send the route for "profile.php" please

Comment: ok so please create an uploads file in the interpage file. So that route should be C:\wamp\www\Interpage\uploads THEN change move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/uploads/".$file_name); TO          move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);

Comment: Look above i edited my reply you need to change that line of code

Comment: Ok is it suppose to be a folder so I can store the pictures ?

Comment: Yes now try again once you change that line of code

Comment: Ohhh I made a file . Hold on

Comment: Still nothing changed

Comment: Ok i see a couple of errors im just editing them. And you have no errors displayed?

Comment: CHANGE $store=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE members SET avatar='$userPic' WHERE username='$username'"); TO $store=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE members SET userPic='$file_name' WHERE username='$username'");

Comment: Let me know if theres any luck with changing that line - if that doesnt work then i have one other solution

Comment: Nothing goes into the directory and the database doesn't change

Comment: Oh the database doesnt change?

Comment: Ok well thats bad. That means its not finding the column in your database. So is $conn correctly defined first. Is it definietly connecting to your database. and secondly are all of your field correct case sensitivity and spelling?

Comment: Hmm have you even got       <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p id="p1">Change profile picture:</p> <br />
         <input type="file" name="image" />
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form> this form in your code exactly like that?

Comment: Ok I just added the same name in the form and now the picture gets uploaded to the directory and database. But the image still doesn't show up on the profile.php page and I can't upload the same picture twice

Comment: Thats good! Ok so now <img id="myImg" src="uploads/<?php echo $img?>"  alt="<?php echo $img ?>" width="200" height="150"> Where you want it to display

Comment: It changes but I get this `Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference on line 44`

Comment: Also how do I hash the image so I can upload the same one as much as I want

Comment: This is line 44 `          $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
`

Comment: Not sure on hashing. Try googling that sorry. Also not sure what that error is im affraid

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that:

1) define your directory of user profile picture in config file using `define()`
    ex : `define('PROFILE_PATH', 'your dir path');`
 2) when user is logged in get image name with sql query with logged in userid / username to get the profile picture name from db
 3) pass the `PROFILE_PATH` and concat your image name after that in  tag

Answer (score 0):

Tested!

```
<?php


    
    $username = isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : "";

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    
    if(!empty($username))
    {
        if(isset($_FILES['image']))
        {
          $errors= array();
          $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
          $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
          $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
          $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
          $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
    
          $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");
    
          if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
             $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
          }
    
          if($file_size > 2097152) {
             $errors[]='File size must be 2 MB';
          }
    
          if(empty($errors)==true)
          {
             move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
    
            $store = "UPDATE users SET userPic='$file_name' WHERE username='$username'";
    
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $store))
            {
                echo "Success";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Update failed!";
            }
    
          }else{
             print_r($errors);
             echo"it failed";
          }
        }
    ?>
    
    <?php
    $getimg = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT userPic FROM users WHERE 
    username='$username'");
    $rows=mysqli_fetch_array($getimg);
    $img = $rows['userPic'];
    
    ?>
    
    
    
     <img id="myImg" src="images/uploads/<?php echo $img?>"  alt="<?php echo $img ?>" width="200" height="150">
    
    
     <?php  
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid Username";
    }
```

You can leave me a comment if you need a guide

## joesphi

Comment: This isn't working . I keep getting this error : `( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$username' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\website\profile.php on line 49`

Comment: Ok i will update the code and make it work locally so you just update the source code Ok?

Comment: Edited your code Above. Replace with existing code and retry

Comment: Wrong::

$store=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users SET userPic='$userPic' WHERE username='$username'");
mysqli_query($conn,$store);

Code pasted above works without changing db columns

Comment: Same thing is happening . I see the box where the image is suppose to be but I only see the name of the picture in the database

Comment: hmm. hold on would have to create a full project

Comment: is profile.php in the root directory ? images/uploads/<?php echo $img?>

Comment: if it's not use ../images/uploads/<?php echo $img?>

Comment: You can view page source from your browser and click on the path. This would tell you if the path is correct. <img id="myImg" src="images/uploads/hello.png"  alt="hello.png" width="200" height="150"> or 

<img id="myImg" src="/images/uploads/hello.png"  alt="hello.png" width="200" height="150">

or 

<img id="myImg" src="../images/uploads/hello.png"  alt="hello.png" width="200" height="150">

or

<img id="myImg" src="./images/uploads/hello.png"  alt="hello.png" width="200" height="150">